# I am getting an unknown error when calling API from retrofit

Tags: android, http, retrofit

I am having an issue with retrofit call.
I am calling a simple forgot password api. Everything looks fine in the code but I am getting an error like okhttp3.ResponseBody$1@somerandomnumber in the response.errorBody()

Here is my json response

```
{
    "error": "False",
    "message": "An email has been sent to your registered email address: . To reset password please check your inbox."
}
```

THis is my calling api reference
 //forgot password

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("api/v1//users/password/reset")
Call<NewBasicModel> forgotPassword(
                              @Field("email")String email);
```

Here is my code in the activity

```
LoginApi loginApi = APIClient.getApiClient().create(LoginApi.class);
    Call<NewBasicModel> call = loginApi.forgotPassword(userEmail);

Log.i("url", call.request().url().toString());


call.enqueue(new Callback<NewBasicModel>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<NewBasicModel> call, @NonNull Response<NewBasicModel> response) {
        if (response.isSuccessful()){

            if ("False".equals(response.body().getError())){
                svProgressHUD.dismiss();
                updateUI(response.body().getMessage());

            }
            else {
                svProgressHUD.dismiss();
                AlertPopup.alertDialogShow(ForgotPassword.this, "Something went wrong, try again", "");
            }

        }

        else {
            svProgressHUD.dismiss();
            AlertPopup.alertDialogShow(ForgotPassword.this, response.errorBody().toString(), "");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<NewBasicModel> call, Throwable t) {

    }
});
```

This is my api client

```
    public static Retrofit retrofit=null;
        private static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();

        private static OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(7, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .readTimeout(7, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .writeTimeout(7, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .build();

        public static Retrofit getApiClient()
        {
            if(retrofit==null)
            {
                //scalar is for text and gson for json obect and arrays
                retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(base_url)
                        .client(okHttpClient)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                        .build();
            }
            return  retrofit;
        }


Here is my response model

public class NewBasicModel {
    @SerializedName("error")
    @Expose
    private String error;
    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    private String message;

    public String getError() {
        return error;
    }

    public void setError(String error) {
        this.error = error;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the response model class in this question. This could be a problem related to GSON Serialization/Mapping. Also add the stacktrace.

Comment: Is the url correct? ```"api/v1//users/password/reset"``` has double ```//```

Comment: Hey I have replaced // with / but still I am getting error. I have added the response model